# TableLayout not occupying whole screen height

Tags: android, height, android-tablayout

I have TableLayout which is just a simple calculator keyboard with TableRows with buttons. Unfortunately, I can't figure out how to make it occupy whole screen height (both in portrait and landscape mode). I tried to achieve it somehow with weights but unfortunately it didn't help. Here is the extract from whole code.

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         android:shrinkColumns="0, 1, 2"
         android:stretchColumns="3">
<TableRow>
    <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:text="Bksp"
            android:onClick="keyboardHandler"/>
    <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/button1_1"
            android:text="AC"
            android:onClick="keyboardHandler"
    />
    <Button
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:text="C"
            android:onClick="keyboardHandler"/>

</TableRow>

<TableRow>
    <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/button12"
            android:text="7"
            android:onClick="keyboardHandler"/>
    <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/button13"
            android:text="8"
            android:onClick="keyboardHandler"/>
    <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/button14"
            android:text="9"
            android:onClick="keyboardHandler"/>

</TableRow>



<TableRow>
    <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/button20"
            android:text="4"
            android:onClick="keyboardHandler"/>
    <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/button21"
            android:text="5"
            android:onClick="keyboardHandler"/>
    <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/button22"
            android:text="6"
            android:onClick="keyboardHandler"/>

</TableRow>


<TableRow>
    <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/button24"
            android:text="1"
            android:onClick="keyboardHandler"/>
    <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/button25"
            android:text="2"
            android:onClick="keyboardHandler"/>
    <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/button26"
            android:text="3"
            android:onClick="keyboardHandler"/>

</TableRow>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TableRow
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:onClick="keyboardHandler"
        android:text="Bksp"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1_1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:onClick="keyboardHandler"
        android:text="AC"
        />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:onClick="keyboardHandler"
        android:text="C"/>

</TableRow>

<TableRow
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button12"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:onClick="keyboardHandler"
        android:text="7"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button13"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:onClick="keyboardHandler"
        android:text="8"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button14"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:onClick="keyboardHandler"
        android:text="9"/>

</TableRow>


<TableRow
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button20"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:onClick="keyboardHandler"
        android:text="4"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button21"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:onClick="keyboardHandler"
        android:text="5"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button22"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:onClick="keyboardHandler"
        android:text="6"/>

</TableRow>


<TableRow
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button24"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:onClick="keyboardHandler"
        android:text="1"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button25"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:onClick="keyboardHandler"
        android:text="2"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button26"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:onClick="keyboardHandler"
        android:text="3"/>

</TableRow>

</TableLayout>
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/VEnDl.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/V3ejJ.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Your Table row is actually taking full width but due to default left gravity it is on left side use bellow code for any row you will come to know what difference it make

```
<TableRow 
        android:background="#666"
        android:gravity="center">
```